# Use input filename in output filename with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

When using FFMPEG with a globbing pattern for the input file list, Can you re-use the input filename in the output filename pattern?

i.e input file pattern `*.jpg` → output filename `%{originalFileName}-%01d.jpg`

I'm using the command line version.

I was unable to find this in the documentation. If you could provide a link to supporting examples or documentation that would be helpful.

Comment: Not with `ffmpeg` by itself but it is possible with scripting. What's your OS?

Comment: Just set the input file name as a variable in script and use that variable in input and output file.

Comment: Are you using Linux, Windows, or Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Since there's still no way to do it and this is OS-less question, here's a solution for every popular OS that I can test, so anything except Mac.

Windows PowerShell:

```
$fname = 'something'; ffmpeg -i "$fname.jpg" "$fname-%01d.jpg"
```

Windows cmd:

```
SET "fname=something" && call ffmpeg -i "%fname%.jpg" "%fname%-%01d.jpg"
```

`call` is needed to ensure the temp env var is set.

Bash:

```bash
fname='something' && ffmpeg -i "$fname.jpg" "$fname-%01d.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

AS REQUESTED : OS = win 10 / powershell

(I can add examples on other OS or shell if needed)

If you're using FFMPEG with a globbing pattern, you can't reuse the filename directly.

But it is doable with little script knowledge.

In this case you can (depending on which language you use) directly use the filename of the current matching `*.jpg` file in the command you're executing. (python or bash scripts are especially easy to write with FFMPEG, make a `foreach` loop to grab any matching file, get the current filename and use it in the FFMPEG command)

If this can help, you can store a filename as a shell variable and use it directly in command line as you would do in a script :

```
$file = "your_filename"
```

(stores a variable `file` with a value of "your_filename")

Then execute your command with your variable :

```
ffmpeg -i .\$file.jpg [...] .\$file.png
```

Or even use an incremental integer value if you transcoding multiple video streams into image sequences :

```
ffmpeg -i .\$file.mp4 [...] .\$file_%03d.png
```

*(realizing after answering that the post is almost 4 years old, I hope it can still help author or other people)*